# error while updating records of Lead

Tags: data-loader, leads, field-update

seeking help here.

I have a sheet to update on Lead where i have State Code and Country Code fields to update. But while updating from Dataloader i am getting error as "invalid cross reference id".

I am not getting where is the issue?

Comment: "**invalid cross reference id**" This error means that in your lookup or master detail relation field you are filling wrong record ID. So either you are filling any text in that field or record ID of some other object.

Comment: i am updating only lead ids here

Comment: Are those lead id's there in Salesforce lead object?

Comment: This may be related to user permissions. Can you manually navigate to the Lead Ids that are causing you this error?